# Question about Priority Queue's in Java

Tags: java, priority-queue

Is it possible to have a Priority Queue with the same key?

so have entries like <100, buy> <100, sell>. then when I have entries with the same key when a buy and sell of that key exists, remove those entries. I am thinking it would work with like an if Statement

If <100, buy> && <100, sell>{
then remove those two entries from queue; }

Something like that.

Comment: for what you describe: why do you need two elements with the same key? just check before you insert a new element if the key is already in, and if it does, instead of adding the new key, remove the old one... (I assume here your key is '100' for your example)

Comment: <100, sell> and <100, buy> are not the same key.  I guess you need to write your own code to check if there is a matching order before you insert a new order in your queue.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense, before I enter into the queue check to see if there already exists. Doesn't seem that difficult at all. Ill give it a try thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q. Is it possible to have a Priority Queue with the same key?

A. Yes it can, However please refer to comments under question there are efficient solutions suggested for your task.

Check slide number 3 for more detail,

http://ww3.algorithmdesign.net/handouts/Heap.pdf

Happy coding!

Comment: it is not theoretical question about general priority queues, it's about java's priority queue

Comment: @amit, So is it not possible in java?

Comment: it is, but your explanation why is wrong (better explanation will refer to the javadocs or give a code sample showing it is possible), plus: though his question is "Is it Possible to have 2 elements in a prio-queue with the same key", it is clear from his question that is NOT what he actually needs (look at the comments for possible better solution).

Comment: p.s. in java, the same element can appear twice in a prio-queue, and they obviously have the same key...

Comment: @amit question was straight forward, [copied and pasted] Is it possible to have a Priority Queue with the same key? answer is yes. As he has no secondary question such as could you please give me an example. That explains Donnie is intelligent enough to write a code for self.

Comment: @Krio thanks for the ppt reference, it helps explain it a bit more. I am intelligent enough to write my own code >.> At least I hope that's what I'm doing when I code and not just face rolling a keyboard, my programs usually work. I was just asking about Priority Queue's not really example, I'm creating it now, and its working out so far.

Comment: @Donnie glad it helped, However Amit's suggested approach(In question's comment) is efficient.

Comment: @krio: please edit your question (add spaces or something) so I can un-downvote, if it helped @Donnie, it means I was wrong.